# cv.glmnet - choose lambda to include specific number of variables

Tags: lasso, glmnet

I am running LASSO regression selection models using `cv.glmnet()`. Predicted is the incidence of a disease and I have 63 coviarates to include.

Of these 63 covariates, I force three to be included in the model by setting the penalty factor to 0.
The results look good and always include the three penalized variables plus a few of the remaining 60 covariates. 
A colleague now suggested that I run the model as I did but also choose lambda.min so that the solution always includes 5 additional covariates (plus the three penalized ones).

How do I do that?
He suggested telling the model to select something like

```
min(lambda[which(n.var==x)])
```

But I don't know how to build it into the model.

Here is what I've got:

```
cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, family="cox", penalty.factor=pen)

coef.min = coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min",penalty.factor=pen)
```

I assume that in order for the model to include my penalized covariates plus extacly 5 out of the 60 remaining, I have to set the "lambda=" argument in `cv.glmnet()`?
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that your colleague had anything fancy in mind -- fit a `glmnet` model with cross-validation as you ordinarily would and then examine how many nonzero features you have at each value of $\lambda$. When you have 5 (or however many) nonzero features, that's the value of $\lambda$ to choose.

`glmnet` even keeps track of this automatically for you. If `lassoFit` is your `cv.glmnet` object, then `lassoFit$nzero` counts the number of nonzero entries at each value of lambda in the sequence. They occur in the order of the lambda sequence.

Comment: (+1) But can you see any point to specifying the no. non-zero features in advance?

Comment: @Scortchi Purely as a statistical abstraction, pre-specifying some number of features doesn’t make sense. On the other hand, I often work on projects where we are only afforded a budget of a certain number of features because memory and CPU are constrained resources.